# SharePoint and RSS feed (Microsoft Teams)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I have created a custom Document Library. Enabled the RSS and picked columns to be shown in the feed.

Is it possible for me to attach/add/link this library to a RSS Feed, so when item is added or changed the RSS Feed will notify me?

I am working with Microsoft Teams, and really want to use their RSS Connector for this purpose. But I get following error when using my SharePoint library feed url,

> This feed is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you probably are not using the correct RSS feed URL. For exames, for blot at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/bg-p/SPBlog, you must supply a feed URL like https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/gxcuf89792/rss/board?board.id=SPBlog.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the right address. Because using it elswhere, works. If I use it in my Outlook it works. But my Microsoft Teams client RSS conecctor does not want to take the SharePoint list RSS url as input :(. Maybe bug in the client.